# Python: Simple server and while loop efficiency

Tags: python, sockets, memory-management, while-loop, client-server

I've seen several examples of simple Python client/server programs on the web. My question is, in order to have the server consistently listening from sunrise to sunset, what is the most efficient way to go?

If I just include an infinite while loop for accepting connections, is that the best way to utilize my resources, or is there a better/more efficient way to program that?

In other words, is the server tutorial [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm) best practice (minus not catching exceptions)?

Comment: This question has no simple answer due to lack of details of what you are trying to achieve and what the requirements of the server are.

Comment: I just need something to listen and accept very small quantities of data, infrequently, throughout the day. I'm talking like 5mb of data an hour, if that. But I do need the program to run all day, just in case someone needs it. My main concern is whether or not leaving a server listening all day is going to eat resources, and what I should do to prevent that.

Comment: Well, then for a lightweight server application without simultaneous connections, a simple while loop might work fine but if you expect a high load or multiple simultaneous requests I think that you need to take that into account. Twisted (http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is a good framework that you might leverage if you do not want to built everything from scratch.

Comment: I have a suggestion. Use the first thing you come up with that works, even if you suspect there's a more efficient solution. Later, if you find a problem or are unsatisfied with performance, then you can ask here or at Code Review respectively.

Comment: Twisted looks cool, but there doesn't appear to be a Python 3 version yet. I'll write the code with a while loop for now, and in the meantime, it looks like I'll need to look up alternatives to Twisted. Thank you HAL for the point in the right direction!

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: And, worry about correctness before efficiency. Regardless of how efficient it is (or isn't), the server you linked to doesn't satisfy your requirement of "consistently listening from sunrise to sunset". A single rogue client can take it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best course of action for you would be to explore the `tulip` library. It's already checked in in the upcoming Python 3.4 (named `asyncio`), but you can start using it today.

- Tulip library on google code: https://code.google.com/p/tulip/source/checkout
- PEP 3156 Asynchronous IO Support Rebooted: the "asyncio" Module: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/